# Android option menu not working

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

As the question says, its not working. When I press the menu button, nothing comes out.

This is the menu Activity:

```
public class AndroidMenuActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewphoto);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
     MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
     menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.edit:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "edit selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotoFlashActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

and a very small menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:title="Edit"/>   

</menu>
```

I don't know what's wrong, the tutorials that I've looked at didn't mention adding the activity to manifest file so I'm not sure whether I have to. And even when I did it doesn't work as well. I've tried cleaning the project but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi, @consprice I just add the menu-related codes and the menu.xml into my activity and I found it works. Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: @Huang I tried deleting the activity creating the new one with exact codes but that doesn't work as well. A small question, Is it necessary to add the activity to the manifest file? And if possible, what else could have caused this. I'm using api level 8 if it helps.

Comment: You should declare all of your own activities in the manifest file, or the system will throw errors when you try to start the activity because the system can't find it.  I just created a completely new project with API 7 and copy all the codes related to menu process, and it worked...

Comment: @Huang I've done that but its not working...Thanks for the help though:)

Comment: Do you override the onKeyDown() or similiar methods, so the menu key message would be intercepted? In such cases, the menu key wouldn't work,as it's disabled.

Comment: @Huang I don't have any onKeyDown() or similar methods. The only methods that I have are in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15152/discussion-between-huang-and-consprice)

Comment: I had the same issue.. As suggested by Huang, I was overriding onkeydown() and that created issues..

Answer (score 0):

This might not be anything, but what happens if you rewrite your onCreateOptionsMenu(...) to look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
     menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
}
```

Comment: What about completely commenting out the call to super.OnCreateOptionsMenu(...) ?  I see in some older apps that I wrote (the option menu is obsolete and has been replaced by ActionBar) that I never made calls to that method.

Comment: that doesn't work as well, in fact, originally, I didn't have the super.onCreateOptionsMenu() at all. Added it after looking at this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/502429/Android/Mobile/Menu

Comment: One more silly question... what is your minSdkLevel and targetSdkLevel set to?  Also what version of Android OS are you testing on?

Finally, do you see the overflow button on your app? (looks like 3 vertically stacked dots.)  If so, do you see your menu option(s) under it if you click it?

Comment: What you want to know? about super or sdk level

Comment: @nick (the one with the lower case n) The reason I ask is because under certain conditions, on some devices the options menu is automatically migrated to the overflow menu.

Comment: @Nick for the first question: `android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="14"` for the second, I don't see the overflow button on the app and to be more precise, nothing appears at all when I press the menu button nothing appears at all

Comment: What version the Android OS are you testing on?

Comment: I'll try what you have on a froyo emulator and get back to you.  If you feel like posting your AndroidManifest.xml that would make it quicker but no worries either way.

Comment: Confirmed that what you have posted works.  I think it's safe to say that the problem is in neither AndroidMenuActivity nor menu.xml.  I'd still be interested in seeing AndroidManifest.xml...

Comment: @Nick it is the problem with the manifest file. After the discussion with Huang, the mistake was that I putting the launcher in the activity of the viewphoto.xml instead of the activity of the menu.xml. Thanks a lot for helping me though:) Maybe you want to change the answer to that since he declined to place his answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its `works` for me perfect.

main.class

```
public class OptionmenuActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add("hello").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add("patel").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add("abc").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add("hello").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menu.add("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.feeds:
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(OptionmenuActivity.this, "feeds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
        return true;

    case R.id.friends:
        Toast msg1 = Toast.makeText(OptionmenuActivity.this, "friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg1.show();
        return true;
    case R.id.about:
        Toast msg2 = Toast.makeText(OptionmenuActivity.this, "about", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg2.show();
        return true;

    case 2:

         Toast msg3 = Toast.makeText(OptionmenuActivity.this, "Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg3.show();
            return true;

    }
    return true;
}
}
```

create the `menu` folder into `res` folder after create `menu.xml` inside `menu` folder.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/feeds"
    android:title="Feeds"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:title="Friends"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="About"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);        
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setTitle("Edit");
}
```

You can also try force:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(true);
```

then...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.edit:
            //DO SOMETHING
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

OR....
You can create the menu on java:

```
private static final int MENU_EDIT = 1;    
MenuItem itemconfig = menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT , 0, "Edit");
            itemconfig.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
            itemconfig.setShowAsAction(2);
```

and onOptionsItemSelected:

```
case: MENU_EDIT
     //DO SOMETHING
     return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

add this to Toolbar

Comment: it is my first answer

Answer (score -1):

change your code like this and chaeck.

```
     @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
 MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
 menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
 return true;
}

 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.edit:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "edit selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotoFlashActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
        default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_custom__list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


                ....code......

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```